# Jquery Tools Tooltip won't disappear

Tags: tooltip, jquery-tools

So this may be a bug but its bugging me, no pun intended.

Here is the issue, when you hover over the input field the tooltip shows up to the right, GREAT! The issue is if you hover over the now appeared tooltip and then move your mouse off of the tooltip (lets say straight down) and into blank page space WITHOUT going back over the input, the tooltip doesnt disappear.  Thoughts?

To see exactly what is happening, check out the code im running here: http://jsfiddle.net/WBdns/

For those of you who dont want to view the demo here is my code:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<label for="ref" class="inline">ICD9 Code
<input name="ref" class="hovertip" type="text" id="ref" tabindex="" title="This code is     located on the Order"placeholder="" required class="" />
</label>​
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
// jQuery Tooltips: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html
$('.hovertip[title]').tooltip({
predelay:100,
offset: [10, 2],
effect:'slide',
slideInSpeed:100,
slideOutSpeed:100,
position:'center right',
opacity:0.8,
layout:'<span/>',
tipClass:'tooltip info ',

events: {
    input:'mouseover focus,blur mouseout',
    }
});
});​
```

Any help is much appreciated!